# Rescale alpha in ggplot to start at 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

n <- 100

df <-
  data.frame(
    x = runif(n),
    y = runif(n),
    size = sample(c(1000, 1500, 2000), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = size)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What I would like is that the scale for alpha would set the lower acceptable  transparency to size = 0, so that the real size = 1000 would be midway transparent between 0 and 2000, rather than almost invisible. This would make the transparency scale a linear one starting at 0. Otherwise, it looks like the importance of those size = 1000 is nothing, while in my case it should be seen as "half" as important as size = 2000.

Comment: `+ scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.5, 1), limits = c(1000, 2000))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `scale_alpha_continuous` [function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_alpha.html) to specify the range for alpha:

```
library(ggplot2)

n <- 100

df <-
  data.frame(
    x = runif(n),
    y = runif(n),
    size = sample(c(1000, 1500, 2000), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = size)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.3, 1))
```

[image]